# PHP form post HTML special characters as plain text

Tags: php, html

I have a basic form to submit comments to a database through PHP and display them on the page via AJAX, and everything works OK but the problem is that simple HTML code like `<script>alert('Message')</script>` or `<h1>Hi!</h1>` is displayed valid HTML and is executed by the client as such.

After doing research I've found that the PHP `htmlspecialchars()` function can prevent XSS code from being executed:

```html
<form method="post" action="<?PHP echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);?>" onsubmit="return post();">
    <textarea id="comment"></textarea>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

the PHP document that processes the form is this:

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_WARNING | E_PARSE | E_NOTICE);

$host="localhost";
$username="user";
$password="password";
$databasename="comments";

$connect=mysql_connect($host,$username,$password);
$db=mysql_select_db($databasename);

if(isset($_POST['user_comm']))
{
  $comment = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['user_comm']);
  $insert=mysql_query("insert into comments values('','$comment',CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)");

  $id=mysql_insert_id();

  $select=mysql_query("select comment,post_time from comments where comment='$comment' and id='$id'");

  if($row=mysql_fetch_array($select))
  {
      $comment = mysql_real_escape_string($row['comment']);
    $time=$row['post_time'];
  ?>
    <div class="comment_div"> 
      <p class="comment"><?php echo stripslashes($comment);?></p>   
      <p class="time"><?php echo date('l d M Y - H:i a', strtotime($time));?></p>
      </div>
  <?php
  }
exit;
}

?>
```

But in my case that isn't working and Javascript code is still executed by the client after the message has been sent. How can I display HTML special characters as plain text on the comments to prevent that?

Comment: You've only protected `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` from XSS here. You need to use `htmlspecialchars` on *any* piece of data that comes from your users, wherever it's shown on the site. Since this is a comments form, you need to use `htmlspecialchars` on the resulting comment when you display it on your website. (Which wouldn't be in this block of code at all.)

Comment: `htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);` doesn't really make any sense - that's not user input, you shouldn't need to protect that.

Comment: You should be executing htmlspecialchars on the $_POST variables you receive into your script when the form is submitted. If you need help with that, please show that section of your script.

Comment: I updated the question and posted all the PHP code.

Comment: What if remove all HTML tags? for that use strip_tags

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why shouldn't I use mysql\_\* functions in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php)

Comment: Why are you using the long-deprecated `mysql_` code library? It was discontinued many years ago and removed entirely in PHP7. No new code should be written using this library. It leaves you vulnerable to SQL injection attacks (due to the lack of parameterised query support) and potentially other unpatched vulnerabilities. Switch to using `mysqli` or `PDO` as soon as possible, and then learn how to write parameterised queries to protect your data from malicious input. See http://bobby-tables.com for a simple explanation of the risks and some sample PHP code to write queries safely.

Comment: @ADyson `PHP_SELF` is attackable. It's generated from client-side data. https://www.webadminblog.com/index.php/2010/02/23/a-xss-vulnerability-in-almost-every-php-form-ive-ever-written/

Comment: @ceejayoz thanks, good point. I didn't know that. I take back that remark then. Will amend my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

htmlspecialchars() replaces special characters by their html code, like < by `&lt;`

Protecting the action of the form has no sense, protect the display of your comment :

```
<p class="comment"><?php echo htmlspecialchars($comment);?></p>
```

Comment: Better to do it when you save the value to the database don't you think? Then you don't waste time doing the same operation again and again every time it gets displayed

Comment: Protecting the action **does** make sense in this case. XSS in `PHP_SELF` is very possible. https://www.webadminblog.com/index.php/2010/02/23/a-xss-vulnerability-in-almost-every-php-form-ive-ever-written/ (Ditching `PHP_SELF` entirely is a better approach, though.)

Comment: @ceejayoz Of course yes, but not to resolve the problem of the OP.

Comment: @ADyson it depends if comment may be an html sequence only protected for display, but needed in another scope, and then has to be stored directly like that

Comment: @iguypouf I'm disagreeing with "protecting the action of the form has no sense". OP is correct to protect it. OP just has a *different* XSS issue to tackle remaining, in the same way.

Answer (score 0):

htmlspecialchars() replaces HTML special characters with an encoded version, for example < is replaced by `&lt;`

As well as protecting your form's "action", you also need to use this to encode any input variables whose data might later be injected into HTML on the screen.

A good time to encode the values would be just before you insert them into the database, so that any time you come to use that data later it can no longer be a danger.

So in your example for you just have the "comment" field, therefore you can encode it like this just before you prepare it for database insertion:

```
$comment = htmlspecialchars($_POST['user_comm']);
$comment = mysql_real_escape_string($comment);
```

---

N.B. Please heed my comment (in the main comments section, above) regarding the use of `mysql_query` and associated functions. You should not be using these for any new code, and for old code you should be planning to replace it. Switch to a supported library as soon as possible.